# how to get user timeline posts using facebook api android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i m using facebook api in android to post/share a status on user wall. but now i want to get all the status from user time line i m using the following code after sucessfull Login and geting the accestoken.

```
JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(mFacebook.request("me"));
String  facebookID = json.getString("id");
String  facebookEmail = json.getString("email");
String  faceBooklastName=json.getString("last_name");
String  faceBookFirstName=json.getString("first_name");
String fUserName = json.getString("username");
```

this returns me all the things correctly and how can i get the posts from user timeline.

Answer (score 2):

You can get user information by using this URL

https://graph.facebook.com/{Your friends FB id}/posts

But before using this,You have to get permissions.